# Facebook FB.getLoginStatus doesn't fire Callback

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api

I know there are some similar questions here on Stackoverflow, but I there wasn't a solution for me in any of them and i'm pretty desperate right now.
I'm writing a Facebook app and it works pretty neat so far. But the FB.getLoginStatus function doesn't fire a Callback for some Users (a small percentage). I was able to reproduce this error on one Machine and it happened only there and only on Chrome. Another User also got this problem also only with Chrome. I found out, that it works if i move the Facebook API Code on an own Page (have no explanation for this, i commented out the rest of the code and it did work sometimes, but many times not). So i moved everything to an own Page and send the data i got over the getLoginStatus function to the other Page. This did work for my PC, but i still got some entries in my Database that it didn't work for other users.
I have no idea why the callback doesn't get called, i hope you can help me, thanks in Advance!

TLDR: The Facebook API doesn't fire a callback at the FB.getLoginStatus function. This only happens on a small percentage of machines and i could only reproduce it with 2 machines (both on Chrome, different User Account, different OS). This is the code i'm using: https://jsfiddle.net/zfyb3zy4/

```html
<script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : '99999999999999999999',
              xfbml      : true,
              version    : 'v2.6'
            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
              if (response.status === 'connected') {
                  localStorage.setItem("f_uid", response.authResponse.userID);
                  FB.api(response.authResponse.userID+"?fields=id,name,email",function(response) {
                      //window.location.href="game.html";
                      localStorage.setItem("name",response.name);
                      localStorage.setItem("email",response.email);
                });
              }
              else {
                FB.login(function (response)
                {
                    if (response.authResponse == null)
                        top.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/anexiagmbh";
                    localStorage.setItem("f_uid", response.authResponse.userID);
                    FB.api(response.authResponse.userID+"?fields=id,name,email",function(response) {
                        //window.location.href="game.html";
                        localStorage.setItem("name",response.name);
                        localStorage.setItem("email",response.email);
                    });
                }
                ,{scope: 'email'});
              }
            }, true);
          };

        function onLogin(response) {
          if (response.status == 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me?fields=first_name', function(data) {
                  var welcomeBlock = document.getElementById('fb-welcome');
                  welcomeBlock.innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + data.first_name + '!';
            });
          }
        }
          (function(d, s, id){
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
```

Comment: Heads up, this apparently still fails sometimes, not user-dependent but basically random for me. Sometimes it fires a callback, sometimes it doesn't. Weird.